# Uncaught RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded. jstree

Tags: javascript, arrays, angularjs, jstree

I get this error and don't know how to resolve it

> Uncaught RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded

I'm trying to build tree with use jstree lib. The data comes from two different http calls. 
I'm getting my initial data like this:

```
           $scope.treeFolders = [];
        $scope.treeFilters = [];
        $scope.tree = [];
    var folders = function () {
        $http.get("folders.json")
        .success(function (res) {
                    angular.forEach(res, function(parent){
                      // console.log(parent)
                        if(!("parent" in parent)){
                          parent.parent = "#"
                        }
                    })

                     $scope.treeFolders = res
                     console.log($scope.treeFolders)
                });
        };
        folders();

    var filters = function(){
            $http.get("child.json")
               .success(function (res) {
                    angular.forEach(res, function(obj){
                        if(!("parent" in obj)){
                          // console.log(obj.folderId)
                            obj.parent = obj.folderId;
                        }
                        // console.log(obj)
                    });

                    $scope.treeFilters = res;
                    console.log($scope.treeFilters)

                });
    };
  filters();
```

console.log returns arrays, for now everything is good. Then I'm using function load to merge two array to one super array

```
    $scope.load = function(){
    // method 1
            $scope.tree = $scope.treeFolders.concat($scope.treeFilters);
          console.log(JSON.stringify($scope.tree))
    // method 2      
        // $scope.treeFolders.forEach(function(item){
        // $scope.tree.push(item)
        // })
        // $scope.treeFilters.forEach(function(item){
        // $scope.tree.push(item)
        // })
        // console.log(JSON.stringify($scope.tree))
        }
```

So as you can see, I tried to get one array with help two methods, both work as well and I get this array

```
  [{
"id":1,
"userId":1,
"createdDt":"2016-06-27T13:05:03.000+0000",
"text":"folder",
"parent":"#"
  },{
"id":2,
"parent":1,
"userId":1,
"createdDt":"2016-06-27T13:26:45.000+0000",
"text":"child folder"
  },{
"id":2,
"folderId":2,
"folder":{"id":2,"text":"child folder"},
"body":"empty",
"user":{"id":1,"name":"User 1"},
"userId":1,
"createdDt":"2016-06-27T13:05:47.000+0000",
"text":"filter 1",
"parent":2
  },{
"id":3,
"folderId":2,
"folder":{"id":2,"text":"child folder"},
"body":"nothing",
"user":{"id":1,"name":"User 1"},
"userId":1,"createdDt":"2016-06-27T13:00:00.000+0000",
"text":"filter 4",
"parent":2
  }]
```

follow by logic jstree docs, my tree should look like

```
* Folder (root) 
---- * Child Folder (parent)
     ---- * Filter 1 (Child)
     ---- * Filter 4 (Child)
```

but instead of this I get the error that somewhere is too much iterations. Could somebody help me find my mistake? Thank you in advance. [**Plunker**](https://plnkr.co/edit/BiXyEiIVbBRgQQNDHDjV) has attached

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Your array contains two items with "id":2, and one of them has a parent which is defined as "id":2 as well. That's probably creating a circular reference.

Try changing the id of your first child item to 4, I did that on your plunker link and the tree loaded like you were looking for.

Comment: oh I got this problem, thanks a lot for explain.. but if I will change it, it breaks DB structure. For example I've got filter with id 5, also I've folder with id 5, I've changed filter id for example on 6, next I want to delete this filter. I send a request to API to delete this filter BUT API sees filter ID is 6 and deleting wrong filter, how to be with that?

Comment: I'm not quite sure I follow, but that sounds like it is a different issue with the API or your data source. For jsTree, if you are defining the parent attribute on each node, it needs to have unique IDs for each item and circular references for parent-child relationships need to be avoided.

Comment: Would it help to specify attributes on each item to use for your filters? Check out "li_attr" and "a_attr" on [JSON source data](https://www.jstree.com/docs/json/)

Comment: Thank you for your help, now I totally figured out